# Unity 2d square need to determine which side is touching what

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a collision system for a square in 2d so that it understands which side and what it is in contact with.
I will be very grateful if you direct to the right path

My implementation:
A bool variable and enum BlockType with block types

```cs
private void Update()
{
//This realization is for all four parties
RaycastHit2D hitTop = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(_topCheak.position.x - .45f,_topCheak.position.y),Vector2.down,.9f,_whatIsGround);
 if (hitTop) CollisionBehaviour(hitTop.collider,DirectionCollision.Top);
         else
         {
             IsTop = false;
             CurrentTopTouch = BlockType.None;
         }
}

 private void CollisionBehaviour(Collider2D collision,DirectionCollision direction)
    {
        collision.TryGetComponent(out BlockBasic block);
        if (block != null)
         {
          switch (direction)
            {
                case DirectionCollision.Top:
                    IsTop = true;
                    CurrentTopTouch = block.BlockType;
                    break;
                case DirectionCollision.Right:
                    IsRight = true;
                    CurrentRightTouch = block.BlockType;
                    break;
                case DirectionCollision.Left:
                    IsLeft = true;
                    CurrentLeftTouch = block.BlockType;
                    break;
                case DirectionCollision.Down:
                    IsDown = true;
                    CurrentDownTouch = block.BlockType;
                    break;
            }
         }
     }
```

Using raycast2d - it is too slow at some points.
What is the best way to do the system I described above?

Comment: why not just use 4 individual colliders? and let them all report back to a central component?

Comment: surely you can just use the collision points to decide which side was hit and use the conventional collision detection

Comment: @derHugo I had an idea to do it that way, but I just wanted to know what the right way to do it would be.

Comment: @BugFinder Through ContactPoint2d?

Comment: @DimaSource "right" is what works for you ;)

Comment: @DimaSource no, as part of the oncollision2d, you get a set of contact points handed to you

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a clean and easy solution: check if the x coordinates of the object you collided with are larger than that of your player. same for the Y coordinates. I don't see why that wouldn't work

Cheers ;)

Comment: works as long as the object is never rotated of course ;)

Comment: Yeah true. The question didn't mention a rotation so I guess I didn't think of that, you're right.